# Matlab: duplicate results with symbolic solver for system of two trigonometric equations?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, nonlinear-functions

For a robotics test on Coursera I need to implement an easy version of inverse kinematics for a two-arm system.
This as a background info. 
I put up the equations in symbolic form that already worked for the forward kinematics. Then I try to solve it and get two identical solution.

```
function [rads1,rads2] = computeRrInverseKinematics(X,Y)

syms theta1 theta2 ;

eqns= [cos(theta1)+cos(theta2+theta1)==X, sin(theta1)+sin(theta2+theta1)==Y];
[theta1, theta2]=solve(eqns, [theta1 theta2]);

rads1=theta1;
rads2=theta1;
```

What I should get or at least I thought is one value for theta1 and theta2 - two elation, two results, normally. 
This is what I get:

```
t1 =

  2*atan(7^(1/2)/3 + 4/3)
 -2*atan(7^(1/2)/3 - 4/3)


t2 =

  2*atan(7^(1/2)/3 + 4/3)
 -2*atan(7^(1/2)/3 - 4/3)
```

Any idea what I did wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: First, dont name the results 'theta12' as the sym variable. Second what is the problem with two solutions? If u just make X,Y symbolic variables too, u will get thegeneral solutions.

Comment: More, dont use sym inside function. Call 'matlabFunction' on the symbolic results (first make X,Y symbolic) to turn it to m function file that will run fast.